# How to call a static JS function defined in other javascript file

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using Meteor JS.
I have a JavaScript function defined in file A which I want to reuse by calling from file B. Example:

File A:

```
function Storeclass(){}
Storeclass.validate=function(){...}
```

From A JavaScript I try to call `StoreClass.validateBasic()` it works but the same call doesn't work from B. Also I tried in B doing `var storeClassObj=new StoreClass();` and `storeClassObj.validate()`. I get error `ReferenceError: StoreClass is not defined`.

Comment: `Storeclass = function(){}?`, meteor will take making this a global variable, accessible between all your JS, also if you put var you are making it a local scoope variable and thats why it dosnt exists on others .js

Comment: how do I make this class global? so that it is visible across my JS files? The var that you are referring to is in file be where I am calling the function not in file A where this function is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/namespacing) about namespacing in Meteor.

The relevant portion is this:

```
// File Scope. This variable will be visible only inside this
// one file. Other files in this app or package won't see it.
var alicePerson = {name: "alice"};

// Package Scope. This variable is visible to every file inside
// of this package or app. The difference is that 'var' is
// omitted.
bobPerson = {name: "bob"};
```

However, later on in the same doc, it says this:

> When declaring functions, keep in mind that function x () {} is just shorthand for var x = function x () {} in JavaScript.

This suggests that the function you have written is *private* to the file A and cannot be accessed from file B, even if load order is correct!

Comment: I removed var in front of the function and it worked, thanks ex : validateBasic = function () {} and took out Storeclass completely.

Answer (score 0):

Because your function in file B might invoke before File A is ready so you have to make sure that all required js files are loaded successfully.

If you are using jQuery then in file B call your function in document ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //File A code
});
```

or in plain JavaScript:

```
(function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // file A code

})();
```